# json file doesn't show up in godot

Tags: file, godot

I'm making a dating sim as my first game and I want to use a JSON file to store all of my dialogue, sprites and B.G.M. kind of like a A.P.I; but the file I wrote won't appear in the godot filesystem section.

[image: here's an image of what i'm talking about.]

I can't get the file path without it, is there a way for it to appear or should I just give up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the File API and read the data into the variable. Like so:

```
var data ={}
var path = "res://data.json"
func _ready():
    var jsonfile = File.new()
    jsonfile.open(path, File.READ)
    data = parse_json(jsonfile.get_as_text())  
    print(data)
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can install JSON Editor asset from Godot marketplace - https://godotengine.org/asset-library/asset/656